# Object.freeze not throwing exception in strict mode when frozen object is mutated

Tags: javascript

When using `Object.freeze()` in strict mode it's not throwing an exception when I attempt to modify a property of a frozen object.

[MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) attempting to mutate a frozen object will throw a `TypeError`:

> In strict mode such attempts will throw TypeErrors

Here's some simple code below:

```
'use strict';

//jshint esnext:true
const func = () => {
  const o = { id: 0 };
  Object.freeze(o);
  o.id = 3;
};

func();
```

**Demo:** https://jsbin.com/fobokipive/edit?js,console

The code does not throw any `TypeError`. I am using Opera which is based on Chromium.

Is this expected behaviour or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it correctly; the problem appears to be with JSBin.
Running the exact same code through JSFiddle (**[as seen here](https://jsfiddle.net/m0wr7ct5/)**) throws the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'id' of object '#'

Running it in a StackSnippet produces the same error as well:

```js
'use strict';

//jshint esnext:true
const func = () => {
  const o = { id: 0 };
  Object.freeze(o);
  o.id = 3;
};

func();
```

And this error is only thrown in strict mode:

```js
//jshint esnext:true
const func = () => {
  const o = { id: 0 };
  Object.freeze(o);
  o.id = 3;
};

func();
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Seconded.. I saw the same thing in jsfiddle.